# Editing Tools Ribbon not showing up in Upload.aspx page - SP2013

Tags: 2013, document-library, ribbon, richhtmlfield

I had created a new Site Column "Description" with the type enhanced rich text and added it to my content type 'Albums' with Folder as parent content type in a SharePoint library.

The New Document button in the ribbon in the library is set to show only option for creating a New Folder(of Ctype : Album)

But on clicking this, The Upload.aspx page loads up with the fields to add all necessary info including the the AlbumDesc field. But it does not have any "Format Text" controls in the ribbon at the top.

If I create the item and select edit properties on the created folder , It has ribbon,and  the Format text option is available on selecting the "Description" field.

Please let me know if that is not available by default or do I need to make any other changes.

Thanks in advance.